# How do I set the File Expire Header with Rackspace CloudFiles .NET API

Tags: rackspace-cloud

I'm trying to set `X-Delete-After` and `X-Delete-At` to a file i'm uploading.

So i tired :

```
FileMetaData.Add("X-Delete-After", "30");
cloudFilesProvider.UpdateObjectMetadata(inStrContainerID, strDesFileName, FileMetaData);
```

but the header did not get recognized.

is that the right approach?

Edit: I'm trying to use `ICloudFilesMetadataProcessor.ProcessMetadata`, but really have no clue how to and am not able to find any documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current release of the SDK, you can include the `X-Delete-After` or `X-Delete-At` value in the `headers` argument to the following calls:

1. [`IObjectStorageProvider.CreateObject`](http://openstacknetsdk.org/docs/html/M_net_openstack_Core_Providers_IObjectStorageProvider_CreateObject.htm)
2. [`IObjectStorageProvider.CreateObjectFromFile`](http://openstacknetsdk.org/docs/html/M_net_openstack_Core_Providers_IObjectStorageProvider_CreateObjectFromFile.htm)

Currently there is no way in the SDK to *change* the value of this header after the file has already been uploaded (e.g. using `UpdateObjectMetadata` as you suggest in the question would set the values `X-Object-Meta-X-Delete-After` or `X-Object-Meta-X-Delete-After`, which is not correct).

Here is a related issue on GitHub:
[#167: How to assign version folder](https://github.com/openstacknetsdk/openstack.net/issues/167)

Answer (score 1):

Gopstar --

EDITED:

After more investigation; I set the X-Delete-After to 1500 and the code worked. Sort of. When viewing the file header information via the dashboard, the X-Delete-At was set.

**However, the result was correct**; the X-Delete-At was equal to what would be 1500 seconds from the time I set it.

Original reply:

I played around; if you set the value higher (for example, I tried X-Delete-After = 3000) it will work.

I do NOT know the lowest number acceptable, but I'm sure someone will chime in with the number.

Hope this give SOME help.